# strtod using classic format?

Tags: swift, parsing, formatting, strtol, strtod

Now functions `strtod` and `strtol` support 
parsing `hex` number format, `infinity`, `NaN`
and other non-standard formats.

But how to convert string to number using only classic format:
`123`, `1.23`, `0.123`, `-123`, `1.23e10`, `1.23e-10` ?

Not: `+123`, `.123`, `0xabcd`, `0123` and etc?

Comment: Which programming language is this?

Comment: I am using `Swift` or `ObjC`

Comment: Probably you will get _way_ better answers if you tag your question accordingly.

Comment: We require exactly "classic format".

Non-standard notation is wrong in our case.

Comment: What exactly *is* the "classic format"?

Comment: I have already mentioned: `123`, `-123`, `1.23`, `-1.23`, `1e23`, `-1e23`, `1.2e3`, `-1.2e3`, `1E23`, `-1E23`, `1.2E3`, `-1.2E3`.

Comment: In your "classic format", what about international users? In Germany, they use `,` for decimal point, e.g. `-1,23`.

Comment: Bottom line, what we're all dancing around is that we don't use `strtod` functions nowadays. If parsing some system generated string (e.g. something you might find in JSON, you'd just do `Int("123")` or `Double("1.23")`. Or if this was a number provided by a user, you'd use `NumberFormatter` to handle input more flexibly, i.e., consistent with the device's locale.